# what is pam_unix in syslogs?

Tags: authentication, logging, syslog, pam, rsyslog

If I am authenticating using PAM, is it a standard/best practice to use `pam_unix` in syslog tags? Who added `pam_unix` in below log: vsftpd process or the PAM module itself which was used in authentication?

For example-

```
Feb 25 13;01:14 hostname vsftpd(pam_unix)[10561]: authentication failure : logname= uid== euuid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=a.b.c.d user=ron
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pam_unix module logs this. See modules/pam_unix/support.c in the pam library sources.